# Difference query lastest result each group when using "group by" clause between MySQL 5.6 and 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is that I used the same SQL query below on MySQL 5.6(Windows) and MySQL 5.7.21(Linux), got different results.

My requirement is getting the lastest row each group, the result from MySQL 5.6 did, but MySQL 5.7 did not get the latest row each group instead earliest row. It seems like that MySQL 5.7 optimized my query "FROM ( SELECT * FROM jc_content ORDER BY sort_date DESC ) cnt" without ordered.

I need MySQL 5.7 to get the same query result like 5.6 does. Is there any tricky I made mistakes?

```
SELECT
    chn.channel_id,
    CONCAT(
        IFNULL(p_chn.channel_path, ''),
        '/',
        IFNULL(chn.channel_path, '')
    ) AS channel_path,
    chnext.channel_name,
    cnt.content_id,
    cntex.title,
    cntex.short_title,
    cntex.release_date,
    cntex.origin,
    cntex.title_img,
    cntex.type_img,
    cntex.description AS descriptionStr,
    cnt.sort_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            jc_content
        ORDER BY
            sort_date DESC
    ) cnt
LEFT JOIN jc_content_ext cntex ON cnt.content_id = cntex.content_id
LEFT JOIN jc_channel chn ON chn.channel_id = cnt.channel_id
LEFT JOIN jc_channel p_chn ON chn.parent_id = p_chn.channel_id
LEFT JOIN jc_channel_ext chnext ON chnext.channel_id = cnt.channel_id
WHERE
    cnt.`status` = 2
AND p_chn.channel_path = 'cp'
GROUP BY
    channel_path
ORDER BY
    cnt.sort_date DESC
```

---

Edited after asking;

Here is my solution, I found it out inadvertently. Just add "limit" after the derived query.

```
SELECT
    chn.channel_id,
    CONCAT(
        IFNULL(p_chn.channel_path, ''),
        '/',
        IFNULL(chn.channel_path, '')
    ) AS channel_path,
    chnext.channel_name,
    cnt.content_id,
    cntex.title,
    cntex.short_title,
    cntex.release_date,
    cntex.origin,
    cntex.title_img,
    cntex.type_img,
    cntex.description AS descriptionStr,
    cnt.sort_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            jc_content
        ORDER BY
            sort_date DESC
        <em>LIMIT 100</em>
    ) cnt
LEFT JOIN jc_content_ext cntex ON cnt.content_id = cntex.content_id
LEFT JOIN jc_channel chn ON chn.channel_id = cnt.channel_id
LEFT JOIN jc_channel p_chn ON chn.parent_id = p_chn.channel_id
LEFT JOIN jc_channel_ext chnext ON chnext.channel_id = cnt.channel_id
WHERE
    cnt.`status` = 2
AND p_chn.channel_path = 'cp'
GROUP BY
    channel_path
ORDER BY
    cnt.sort_date DESC
```

As you can see, when I add the limit it works. I tried to figure out and I used "EXPLAIN" SQL, It showed below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRCYH.png)

Without "limit" by "EXPLAIN" it showed below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkrTP.png)

Thus I could infer from the upons that MySQL 5.7 does optimize my query "FROM ( SELECT * FROM jc_content ORDER BY sort_date DESC ) cnt" without ordered, when I put limit behind, it becomes a derived table then it works. I used "EXPLAIN" on MySQL 5.6, it did not optimize the "FROM ( SELECT * FROM jc_content ORDER BY sort_date DESC ) cnt", it showed select_type of "DERIVED" and queried all rows.

Also I found the tricky point, once I changed the limit value, like "FROM ( SELECT * FROM jc_content ORDER BY sort_date DESC LIMIT 400 ) cnt", "EXPLAIN" that, it showed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmcys.png)

I tested the change of the limit value, I found that when the value is greater than 397, it would query all table rows(Total row count is 33021). Probably it's optimized mechanism of MySQL 5.7

Comment: please display the 2 different results.

Comment: and if your `derived table` does not do anything magical then just `anchor that table`

Comment: the results I query for are articles. MySQL 5.6 results are latest articles, 5.7 gets earliest articles.